# Need to upload file and replace the existing one

Tags: javascript, php, html, upload, mp3

I need to execute the following either in JS or PHP (and HTML):

Upload a file on the server via HTML form; then
rename the file automatically to "main.mp3"; and
if the file already exists (ofc it does), replace it.

That's it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php send form code, you can check if files exist, if exist, unlink and upload the new file:

```
<?php
$directory_save = "example/directory/for/save/";
$file_name = $_FILES["myupload"]["name"];
$new_file_name = "main.mp3";

if (file_exists($directory_save . $file_name)) {
    //if file exists in directory
    unlink($file);
}

//upload file with new name and check if uploaded
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myupload']['tmp_name'], $directory_save . $new_file_name)) {
    echo "file uploaded";
} else {
    echo "error on upload";
}
?>
```

Remember that in $_FILES["myupload"], the "myupload" is the name of the input in the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (file_exists($fullpath_to_file_you_want_to_remove)){
   if(unlink($fullpath_to_file_you_want_to_remove)){
     //You can go ahead and move new file to desired destination and also 
     //save to database as the case may be.
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['name_of_file_input']['tmp_name'], desired_destination + name_of_new_file)
   }
}
```

Before getting to this point you must have checked the new file for errors and other forms of validation like size, width & height, errors, etc. Only if these validation conditions are met will the code get to this point.